# Unexpected output when printing directly to text video memory

Tags: c, x86, kernel, bootloader, osdev

I am developing a kernel in C and created something to print on screen on video memory. I expected that the first byte in video memory would be the character to print and the second byte tells the color. But my program has something different but it works!! It is very unexpected and unusual.

My kernel code -

```
#define VIDEO_MEM 0xb8000

void write_string( int colour, const unsigned char *string );

void main()
{
    unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_MEM;
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        *vid = ' ';
        *(vid+2) = 0x1f;
        vid += 2;
    }
    write_string(0x1f,"The Kernel has been loaded successfully!!");
}

void write_string( int colour, const unsigned char *string ) {
    unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_MEM;
    while(*string != 0)
    {
        *(vid) = *string;
        *(vid+2) = colour;
        ++string;
        vid+=2;
    }
}
```

It prints the character on `*vid` and the color on `*(vid+2)` and then increments the `vid` by 2. It should then replace and print the next char on `*(vid+2)`. So, the color should go but it still works.

Also, the color should be on `*(vid+1)`

When I use `*(vid+1)` instead of `*(vid+2)` to print the string, the screen shows down arrow characters (with ACII code `0x1f` which I wanted to be the color) replacing the entire string.

Why does the code behave so unusual??

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

I have edited my code and now it prints string. But another problem arose. I added a support for printing on particular line number. But now this shifts the string backwards by one character.

```
void write_string( int colour, const unsigned char *string, int pos ) {
    unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_MEM;
    vid+=pos*160;
    while(*string != 0)
    {
        *vid = colour;
        *(vid+1) = *string;
        ++string;
        vid+=2;
    }

}
```

So, If I tell it to print on line 10, it prints the first character on the last character of the 9th line and then continues.

I also have a character printing function that justs prints curly braces (`}`) instead of the given character and that too one character backwards of the given position (like the error in the `write_string` function). Also it doen't change the character background color given as argument.

```
void putChar(char character, short col, short row, char attr) {
    unsigned char* vid_mem = (unsigned char *) VIDEO_MEM;
    int offset = (row*80 + col)*2;
    vid_mem += offset;
    if(!attr) {
        attr = 0x0f;
    }
    *vid_mem = (attr<<8)+character;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

My Boot Loader:

```
[org 0x7c00]

KERNEL equ 0x1000

mov [BOOT_DRIVE],dl

mov bp,0x9000
mov sp,bp

mov bx, msgReal
call print_string

call load_kernel

call switch_to_pm

jmp $

%include 'boot/bios.ASM'

%include 'boot/gdt.ASM'
%include 'boot/protected_mode.ASM'
%include 'boot/print32.ASM'

[bits 16]
load_kernel:
    mov bx,msgKernel
    call print_string

    mov bx, KERNEL
    mov dh, 15
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    call disk_load
    ret

[bits 32]

BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, msgProt
    call print_string32
    call KERNEL
    jmp $

BOOT_DRIVE db 0
msgReal db "Booted in 16-bit mode",0
msgProt db "Successfully switched to 32-bit mode",0
msgKernel db "Loading the kernel onto memory",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

bios.ASM -

```
;BIOS Functions
[bits 16]

print_string:
    pusha
    mov cx,bx
    mov ah,0x0e
    printStringStart:
    mov al,[bx]
    cmp al,0
    je done
    int 0x10
    inc bx
    jmp printStringStart
    done:
    popa
    ret

print_word:
    pusha
    mov ax,0x0000
    mov cl,0x10
    mov al,bh
    div cl
    call printDig
    mov al,bh
    and al,0x0f
    call printDig
    mov ax,0x0000
    mov al,bl
    div cl
    call printDig
    mov al,bl
    and al,0x0f
    call printDig
    popa
    ret

printDig:
    cmp al,0x9
    jg alpha
    add al,'0'
    mov ah,0x0e
    int 0x10
    jmp pDigDone
    alpha:
    sub al,0xa
    add al,'A'
    mov ah,0x0e
    int 0x10
    pDigDone:
    ret

hex_prefix: db '0x',0

disk_load:
    push dx
    mov ah,0x02
    mov al,dh
    mov ch,0x00
    mov dh,0x00
    mov cl,0x02
    int 0x13
    jc disk_error
    pop dx
    cmp dh,al
    jne disk_error
    ret

disk_error:
    mov ah,0x0e
    mov al,'X'
    int 0x10
    mov bx,errMsg
    call print_string
    jmp $

errMsg:
    db "Disk Read Error....."
    times 80-20 db " "
    db 0
```

gdt.ASM -

```
gdt_start:
gdt_null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0

gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

protected_mode.ASM -

```
[bits 16]
switch_to_pm:
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm

[bits 32]
init_pm:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp,0x90000
    mov esp,0x90000

    call BEGIN_PM
```

print32.ASM -

```
[bits 32]

VIDEO_MEM equ 0xb8000
DEF_COLOR equ 0x0f

print_string32:
    pusha
    mov edx,VIDEO_MEM

print_string32_loop:
    mov al, [ebx]
    mov ah, DEF_COLOR

    cmp al,0
    je print_string32_end

    mov [edx],ax

    inc ebx
    add edx,2
    jmp print_string32_loop

print_string32_end:
    popa
    ret
```

I also add a kernel_start.asm file just before the kernel while linking to call the main function -

```
[bits 32]
[extern main]
call main
jmp $
```

And here's my make file -

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard drivers/*.c kernel/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard kernel/*.h drivers/*.h)

OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

all: os-image

os-image: boot/boot_sector.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > $@

kernel.bin: kernel/kernel_start.o ${OBJ}
    ld -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

%.o : %.c
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.asm
    nasm $< -f elf64 -o $@

%.bin : %.asm 
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

clean:
    rm -fr kernel/*.o
    rm -fr drivers/*.o   
    rm -fr boot/*.bin
    rm -fr os-image *.bin *.o
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch I corrected the mistake. Now another problem arose. I have specified it in the EDIT. Can you please check it out?

Comment: But the code above atleast prints the write things - though I have set the first byte as an attribute and the second the character. The problem is that the `write_string` function doesn't print on the write position and the `putChar` doesn't print anything but just puts a `}`. It doesn't even put the color on the memory for the character. @MichaelPetch

Comment: VIDEO_MEM is 0xb8000 @MichaelPetch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the changes suggested in other answer and comments, your problem doesn't seem to be reproducible for me. The following code works for me. I've tried to maintain how you coded it just so it makes sense to you:

```
#define VIDEO_MEM 0xb8000

void write_string( unsigned char colour, const char *string );
void write_string_line( unsigned char colour, const char *string, int pos );
void putChar(char character, short col, short row, unsigned char attr);

/* Place this at top of file as first code in kernel.o */
__asm__ ("call main\r\n" \
         "cli\r\n" \
         "hlt\r\n"
         );

void main()
{
    volatile unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_MEM;
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        *vid = ' ';
        *(vid+1) = 0x1f;
        vid += 2;
    }
    write_string(0x1f,"The Kernel has been loaded successfully!!");
    write_string_line(0x1f,"Testing Here!!",1);
    putChar('Z',3,3,0xf3);
}

void write_string( unsigned char colour, const char *string ) {
    volatile unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_MEM;
    while(*string != 0)
    {
        *(vid) = *string;
        *(vid+1) = colour;
        ++string;
        vid+=2;
    }
}

void write_string_line( unsigned char colour, const char *string, int pos ) {
    volatile unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_MEM;
    vid+=pos*160;
    while(*string != 0)
    {
        *vid = *string;
        *(vid+1) = colour;
        ++string;
        vid+=2;
    }

}

void putChar(char character, short col, short row, unsigned char attr) {
    volatile unsigned char* vid_mem = (unsigned char *) VIDEO_MEM;
    int offset = (row*80 + col)*2;
    vid_mem += offset;
    if(!attr) {
        attr = 0x0f;
    }
    *(unsigned short int *)vid_mem = (attr<<8)+character;
    /* This would do the same as line above
    *vid_mem     = character;
    *(vid_mem+1) = attr;
    */
}
```

I've added the `__asm__` at the beginning to make sure that code is the first to appear in the generated object file. It likely works without it. I've modified all your `*vid` pointers to be `volatile` . Since video is memory mapped IO you don't want to have the compiler potentially remove screen writes when it optimizes. Likely your code will work without `volatile`, but it is proper to add it here to avoid potential problems.

When run *BOCHS* this code produces this screen output:

[image]

If you use the code provided here and it doesn't work that would suggest the issue you are having is likely related to the a code you write in your bootloader that read the disk, enabled A20, set the GDT, entered protected mode, and then called into your *C* code. It is also possible problems could occur depending on how you compile and link your kernel.

---

### Likely Cause of Undefined Behavior

After all the code and the make file were made available in *EDIT 2* it became clear that one significant problem was that most of the code was compiled and linked to 64-bit objects and executables. That code won't work in 32-bit protected mode.

In the make file make these adjustments:

- When compiling with *GCC* you need to add `-m32` option
- When assembling with *GNU Assembler* (*as*) targeting 32-bit objects you need to use `--32`
- When linking with *LD* you need to add the `-melf_i386` option
- When assembling with *NASM* targeting 32-bit objects you need to change `-f elf64` to `-f elf32`

A preferable option to using a 64-bit compiler and tool chain from the host environment is to create a [cross compiler toolchain for i686 or i386](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler).

Comment: This doesn't work. The code for clearing the screen prints the down arrow character (with ASCII = 0x1f) and up arrows are printed instead of the two messages. A blinking curly braces `}` is printed with grey background by the putChar function. My code for clearing screen works fine but rest doesn't.

Comment: @AneeshSharma That confirms my suspicion that whatever problem you have is likely not related to the _C_ code itself. It is likely something you have done wrong in loading the kernel file into memory, or something with the segments, GDT the paramaters you use to assemble/build the images etc. The fact such simple code fails for you and works for me with my own bootloader is a pretty good indication your bootloader has done something wrong, or has not done something it should have. If you made ALL your code available and the commands that you use to build it then I might be able to help you.

Comment: @AneeshSharma : My code also works on Bochs. By the way, your edit and screen image should be added to your question, not my answer.

Comment: Fine I will add all the code. And I am using an Ubuntu bash shell on windows 10 for compiling my code using a make file. And sorry for the Image

Comment: @AneeshSharma : All the code, and a linker script if you have it and the commands you use to assemble / compile / link  and make the disk image with. Windows Subsystem for Linux should be fine as it is pretty much Ubuntu.

Comment: @AneeshSharma : it appears you are compiling and linking your code for 64-bit (and running it in 32-bit protected mode). That won't work. You need to generate 32-bit code. So when compiling with _GCC_ you need to add `-m32`, when linking with _LD_ you need to add `-melf_i386` and when assembling with NASM you need to change `-f elf64` to `-f elf32`

Comment: This works!! Thanks @MichaelPetch. Now my code works fine.

Comment: @AneeshSharma Great, had a feeling it was somewhere outside the _C_ code.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.
Each VGA cell is of 2 bytes long, First byte stores Character while the second byte stores the color.
Also make sure you make marked the pointer volatile. To avoid any type of unexpected changes(or **optimizations**) made by the compiler on that local field.

```
void write_string( int colour, const unsigned char *string )
{
    volatile unsigned char *vid = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_MEM;
    while( *string != 0 )
    {
        *vid++ = *string++;
        *vid++ = colour;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use *(vid) for first video character for color