# While loop not writing to video memory

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, osdev

I'm writing my own OS as a homework assignment and I'm having some trouble with my C code. I've set up my boot headers and linker files as well as a simple assembler script which prints 'H' and then calls my C code. The assembler code prints to video memory fine (I'm printing to 0xb8000) but my while loop in my C code is not.

```
const char *str = "My first kernel";
char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8002; //My ASM code writes to 0xb8000 for testing purposes
while(*str){
    *vidptr++ = 0x07;
    *vidptr++ = *str++;
}
vidptr[0] = 0x07;
vidptr[1] = 'f';
```

The 'H' and 'f' characters print just fine, but my loop isn't printing anything to the screen. I've tried multiple ways of writing this loop such as

```
unsigned int j = 0;
char c;
while(c = *(str++)){
    vidptr[j] = 0x07;
    vidptr[j+1] = c;
    j+=2;
}
```

and of course I've tried

```
int i, j;
while(str[i] != '\0'){
    vidptr[j] = 0x07;
    vidptr[j+1] = str[i];
    i++;
    j+=2;
}
```

but nothing seems to work. I'm rather confused.

EDIT:

I made a slight change which resulted in the characters in str to be printed to the screen. I simply changed vidptr to a pointer to an integer.

```
int *vidptr = (int*)0xb8000;
```

This seems to have worked. But, I'm still confused as to why it wasn't working when vidptr was declared as a char pointer. Even when I declared it volatile I still was not getting output to the screen.

EDIT 2:

By request, here is the working ASM code.

```
global start
extern main

section .text

bits 32

start:
    mov word [0xb8000], 0x0748
    mov esp, stack_space
    call main
    hlt

section .bss
resb 8192
stack_space:
```

main is the function in my C code that I have provided above.

A complete copy of my source code can be found in my [Github Repository](https://github.com/lucasrudd/Simple-32-Bit-Operating-System/blob/master/Makefile). My Makefile is:

```
default: build

.PHONY: clean

build/boot_header.o: multiboot_header.asm
    mkdir -p build
    nasm -f elf64 multiboot_header.asm -o build/boot_header.o

build/asmk.o: kernel.asm
    mkdir -p build
    nasm -f elf64 kernel.asm -o build/asmk.o

build/ckern.o: kernel.c
    gcc -m64 -c kernel.c -o build/ckern.o

build/kernel.bin: build/boot_header.o build/asmk.o build/ckern.o link.ld
    ld -n -o build/kernel.bin -T link.ld build/boot_header.o build/ckern.o build/asmk.o

build/os.iso: build/kernel.bin grub.cfg
        mkdir -p build/isofiles/boot/grub
        cp grub.cfg build/isofiles/boot/grub
        cp build/kernel.bin build/isofiles/boot/
        grub-mkrescue -o build/os.iso build/isofiles

run: build/os.iso
    qemu-system-x86_64 -curses -cdrom build/os.iso

build: build/os.iso

clean:
    rm -rf build
```

Comment: I'm missing a `volatile` on that variable declaration.

Comment: You may have some issue outside of this code that you are overlooking.  (BTW, `i` and `j` are uninitialized in the last version.)

Comment: Is this running in protected mode?

Comment: "The 'H' and 'f' characters print just fine" - what `H`?

Comment: @RadLexus : I suspect the `H` is printed by the assembly code that he didn't show us.

Comment: I'm with dhke in marking vidptr to `volatile` data since it is memory mapped IO and the compiler may optimize the loop. My other question would be - Did you verify that you can print characters fromstr? It is possible for some reason that `str` isn't the characters you thought they were. What happens if you do `vidptr[0] = 0x07; vidptr[1] = str[0];`, does it print `M`?

Comment: @SimonRichter yes, this is running in protected mode.

Comment: @RadLexus I have some assembly code that is not included in this post. It prints an 'H' to the screen.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, yes, an 'M' is printed when I manually set vidptr[1] = str[0]; Is it necessary to declare vidptr volatile?

Comment: Have you tried using `volatile char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8002;`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch : Yes I did, it still did not print anything to the screen. However, I have found a solution (although not ideal in my opinion since I still don't understand what the initial problem is). See my edit.

Comment: It seems that the way video data is laid out in memory is not the way you expect. In particular, more than one byte is used for each character. (Which makes sense. How would you indicate color, underlining, and so on with just one byte per character?)

Comment: It would have helped to perhaps have the working asm code with the c code.  We'd have been able to see that one prints in words while another prints in chars.

Comment: When you say it didn't print the string, did it print something but display unusual characters in the wrong colors?

Comment: The reason I ask is that your code has encoded the bytes in the video array incorrectly. Each cell on the video display is made up of 2 bytes. If you access the video memory as an array of characters then the character to print is in the first byte of a cell and the color in the second byte. You have that reversed. What if you do `while(*str){
    *vidptr++ = *str++;
    *vidptr++ = 0x07;
}`

Comment: In your update you did `mov word [0xb8000], 0x0748`. That moves the 16-bit word 0x0748 to 0xb8000 . Because x86 is little endian a word is stored least significant byte to most significant byte when placed in memory. So 0xb8000 would have 0x48 in it and 0x07 at 0b8001 . See my comment above about you having the bytes reversed.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm glad someone else noticed this. I found that odd, but if I reverse the two operations (like you have suggested in your comment) then again no characters were printed within the loop, but a random background color was printed where the character 'f' was expected to be. I interpreted this as meaning that the hex representation of the character 'f' was interpreted as a color code. When I changed vidptr to a pointer to an integer (see my first edit) I was still required to encode the bytes as color code first, then character. I am using qemu-system-x86_64 to run my OS.

Comment: That makes no sense. Exactly what code are you using to write the string now? An int is 4 bytes, so if you are using post increment ++ then the pointer is being advanced by 4. So I can only imagine you have not only altered the type on the array, but you have also altered your loop.`short` instead of `int` would also make more sense since `short` is 2 bytes.

Comment: @Michael Petch, the code I am using is   `const char *str = "My first kernel";
    short int *vidptr = (short int*)0xb8000;
    while(*str){
        *vidptr++ = 0x07;
        *vidptr++ = *str++;
    }` and this prints to the screen "first kernel" in grey-on-black with (what appears to be) a leading space in front.

Comment: That is still wrong. `short int` is 2 bytes. If you use `++` that adds 2 to the pointer.

Comment: I would expect this to work though `const char *str = "My first kernel";
short int *vidptr = (short int *)0xb8000;
while(*str)
    *vidptr++ = (0x07 << 8) | *str++;` . Of course I still recommend `volatile` on vidptr.

Comment: That prints the following (both with and without the `volatile` keyword) http://imgur.com/wChTZfZ

Comment: This is a dumb question, but after you use my code (I hope you tested it exactly) did you stop your program there? Do you have code after that which might overwrite? I can say this for certain, if you used exactly what I gave you as code then there is something wrong elsewhere. I finally took the code I just gave you and tossed it in a sample 32-bit kernel (running on qemu x86_64) and I got the expected output.

Comment: This is the output I get: http://i.imgur.com/AfPOTkp.png

Comment: An interesting thing to note about your output `rtkre` is that it isn't entirely random. `rtkre` happen to appear in order in the string "My fi**r**s**t** **k**e**r**n**e**l" . the letter rtkre are every second character after `My fi`

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that would cause strange things like this is if somehow you compiled 64-bit code and then attempted to run it in 32-bit protected mode. Your ASM code looks like it was designed for 32-bit. Make sure when you compile with NASM that you use `-f elf32`, when using `gcc` make sure you have `-m32` when compiling _C_ files, and when linking make sure you use `-melf_i386` . Your code looks very simple, so it has me thinking that 64-bit code is being decoded in a 32-bit environment which can cause weird and wonderful problems.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you for being so helpful. I have uploaded my code in its entirety to github, here is the repository URL: [link]https://github.com/lucasrudd/Simple-32-Bit-Operating-System     If you have time please take a look at my code. I am using the Bash shell on Windows 10 to run my code. The repository includes the make file, bootheader file, the main C file, the main asm file (please ignore the 64 bit asm file), the grub configuration file, and a linker file. At the moment, this code prints " first kernel" to the screen when run. I suspect an issue in my make file.

Comment: See my last comment, I posted it before you put up a link to your source code. It is appears my guess above about 64-bit code running in 32-bit protected mode is causing problems. I happened to glance at your Makefile and that seems to be the case. You have compiled everything as 64-bit

Comment: @MichaelPetch I believe that is the issue. I was compiling with `-f elf64`. Should I also run qemu in 32 bit?

Comment: You have to compile as 32-bit (NASM code, GCC code and linking). You can run the 32-bit kernel in both qemu-system-i386 and qemu-system-x86_64. If you had created code that put the CPU in 64-bit mode (which you don't do) then you would need qemu-system-x86_64

Comment: That was the issue. @MichaelPetch, you are a saint. Thank you. I was compiling in 64 bit in case I wanted to add 64 bit functionality in the future. I was under the impression that a 64 bit compilation was backwards compatible with a 32 bit system and is this not the case?

Comment: 64-bit compiled code doesn't work properly in 32-bit protected mode - correct.

Comment: I discovered I had answered a similar question previously, this question is a possible duplicate of [Unexpected output when printing directly to text video memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807710/unexpected-output-when-printing-directly-to-text-video-memory) . The last part of my answer pretty much answers the question about compiling/linking/assembling 32-bit code. If that answer effectively solved your problem, you can consider upvoting it.

Comment: And that, gentlemen, is why you post [mcve] right away so you don't waste people's time guessing. @MichaelPetch you earned your upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above:

> In your update you did `mov word [0xb8000], 0x0748`. That moves the 16-bit word 0x0748 to 0xb8000 . Because x86 is little endian a word is stored least significant byte to most significant byte when placed in memory. So 0xb8000 would have 0x48 in it and 0x07 at 0b8001 . See my comment above about you having the bytes reversed. – Michael Petch Nov 21 '16 at 19:33

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't his biggest problem. He was generating 64-bit code and running it on a processor still running in 32-bit mode. His kernel was being decoded incorrectly and caused the video output to work unexpectedly. Originally I thought I had marked this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807710/unexpected-output-when-printing-directly-to-text-video-memory . I've marked it as a duplicate.