# Why does passing a char to a function change it's value in c?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, qemu, osdev

I am currently following [this workbook](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) on build an operating system.

My intention is to write a 64-bit kernel. I have got as far as loading the "kernel" code and writing individual characters to the frame buffer while in text mode.

My problem appears when I add a level of indirection to writing a single character to the frame buffer by wrapping the code in a function. It would appear that the char value passed into the function is being corrupted in some way.

I have three files:

### bootloader.asm

```
; bootloader.asm
[org 0x7c00]
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

mov bp, 0x9000
mov sp, bp

; load the kernel from boot disk
mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
mov dl, dl ; boot drive is set to dl
mov ah, 0x02 ; bios read sector
mov al, 15 ; read 15 sectors    
mov ch, 0x00 ; cylinder 0
mov cl, 0x02 ; read from 2nd sector
mov dh, 0x00 ; select head 0
int 0x13

; THERE COULD BE ERRORS HERE BUT FOR NOW ASSUME IT WORKS

; switch to protected mode
cli

lgdt [gdt.descriptor]

mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax
jmp CODE_SEGMENT:start_protected_mode

[bits 32]
start_protected_mode:
    mov ax, DATA_SEGMENT
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    call KERNEL_OFFSET
    jmp $

[bits 16]
gdt: ; Super Simple Global Descriptor Table
.start:
.null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0
.code:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
.data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
.end:
.descriptor:
    dw .end - .start
    dd .start

CODE_SEGMENT equ gdt.code - gdt.start
DATA_SEGMENT equ gdt.data - gdt.start

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

### bootkernel.asm

```
[bits 32]
[extern main]
[global _start]
_start:
    call main
    jmp $
```

### kernel.c

```
// LEGACY MODE VIDEO DRIVER
#define FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS 0xb8002
#define GREY_ON_BLACK 0x07
#define WHITE_ON_BLACK 0x0f

void write_memory(unsigned long address, unsigned int index, unsigned char value)
{
    unsigned char * memory = (unsigned char *) address;
    memory[index] = value;
}

unsigned int frame_buffer_offset(unsigned int col, unsigned int row)
{
    return 2 * ((row * 80u) + col);
}

void write_frame_buffer_cell(unsigned char c, unsigned char a, unsigned int col, unsigned int row)
{
    unsigned int offset = frame_buffer_offset(col, row);
    write_memory(FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS, offset, c);
    write_memory(FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS, offset + 1, a);
}

void main()
{
    unsigned int offset = frame_buffer_offset(0, 1);
    write_memory(FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS, offset, 'A');
    write_memory(FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS, offset + 1, GREY_ON_BLACK);

    write_frame_buffer_cell('B', GREY_ON_BLACK, 0, 1);
}
```

The .text section is linked to start from 0x1000 which is where the bootloader expects the kernel to start.

The linker.ld script is

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x1000;

    .text : { *(.text) } /* Kernel is expected at 0x1000 */
}
```

The Make file that puts this all together is:

```
bootloader.bin: bootloader.asm
    nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin

bootkernel.o: bootkernel.asm
    nasm -f elf64 bootkernel.asm -o bootkernel.o

kernel.o: kernel.c
    gcc-6 -Wextra -Wall -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o

kernel.bin: bootkernel.o kernel.o linker.ld
    ld -o kernel.bin -T linker.ld bootkernel.o kernel.o --oformat binary

os-image: bootloader.bin kernel.bin
    cat bootloader.bin kernel.bin > os-image

qemu: os-image
    qemu-system-x86_64 -d guest_errors -fda os-image -boot a
```

I've taken a screen shot of the output that I am getting. I expect 'A' to appear in the 0th column of the 1st row and for 'B' to appear on the 1st column of the 0th row. For some reason I am getting another character.

[image: Screenshot]

### Output of gcc-6 -S kernel.c

```
    .file   "kernel.c"
    .text
    .globl  write_memory
    .type   write_memory, @function
write_memory:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -28(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, %eax
    movb    %al, -32(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -28(%rbp), %edx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    addq    %rax, %rdx
    movzbl  -32(%rbp), %eax
    movb    %al, (%rdx)
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   write_memory, .-write_memory
    .globl  frame_buffer_offset
    .type   frame_buffer_offset, @function
frame_buffer_offset:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    sall    $2, %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    sall    $4, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   frame_buffer_offset, .-frame_buffer_offset
    .globl  write_frame_buffer_cell
    .type   write_frame_buffer_cell, @function
write_frame_buffer_cell:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    %esi, %eax
    movl    %edx, -28(%rbp)
    movl    %ecx, -32(%rbp)
    movb    %dil, -20(%rbp)
    movb    %al, -24(%rbp)
    movl    -32(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %edx, %esi
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    frame_buffer_offset
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movzbl  -20(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $753666, %edi
    call    write_memory
    movzbl  -24(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
    leal    1(%rdx), %ecx
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movl    %ecx, %esi
    movl    $753666, %edi
    call    write_memory
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   write_frame_buffer_cell, .-write_frame_buffer_cell
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $1, %esi
    movl    $0, %edi
    call    frame_buffer_offset
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    $65, %edx
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $753666, %edi
    call    write_memory
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    $7, %edx
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $753666, %edi
    call    write_memory
    movl    $0, %ecx
    movl    $1, %edx
    movl    $7, %esi
    movl    $66, %edi
    call    write_frame_buffer_cell
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~16.04) 6.2.0 20160901"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Note: `i` is not defined in `void main()`.

Comment: Why does `unsigned int frame_buffer_offset(int col, int row)` take signed arguments and returns an unsigned one without any safeguards in code for a negative argument?  I'd expect uniformity between the arguments and return value.  Suggest `return 2 * ((row * 80u) + col);` to avoid `int` overflow

Comment: `#define FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS 0xb8002` is surprising.  Maye it should be `0xb8000`?

Comment: Why do you expect to see A at (0,1) and B at (1,0) when in both cases you are passing `i` and `0` to `col` and `row`?

Comment: @chux that flaw seems to be in the definition of `unsigned int frame_buffer_offset(int col, int row)` since `write_frame_buffer_cell()` has `unsigned` arguments.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes.  In the end, OP has not posted enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: really, I would have thought that was too much code, but maybe it is just not the right code to replicate the problem?

Comment: The output of `gcc -S kernel.c` would be very useful.

Comment: @chux Thanks, it was previously in a loop. I've also updated the function to be uniform + use `80u`. I didn't vet the code I posted up to remove change I'd made while randomly making changes in frustration.

Comment: Unless I am misreading this, your main problem will actually be that your are generating 64-bit _C_ code but you only have the processor in 32-bit protected mode. This will cause the instructions to be decoded incorrectly (64-bit code generated from _GCC_ will not run properly unless in 64-bit mode). If you are in 32-bit protected mode you need to generate your files as 32-bit objects not as 64-bit

Comment: @chux 
0xb000 actually seems to point to a cell just before the frame buffer on my qemu
`qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.7.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2016 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers`

Comment: @weathervane Thanks for that, it is meant to be A at (0,1) and B at (1,0) but I left in the index from a loop I had when running some other tests on the problem.

Comment: Jasper you may wish to read my comment above. This is actually a duplicate of another SO question I answered previously (I just can't find the duplicate LOL). You can't generate 64-bit _C_ code and run it in 32-bit protected mode and have it work as expected. You may not want to believe it but in simple test code that displays to the screen this is the type of behaviour you'd see.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks! That makes a lot more sense. I am trying now.

Comment: Cocerning this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477719/why-does-passing-a-char-to-a-function-change-its-value-in-c?noredirect=1#comment74011546_43477719), suggest posting the `kernel.c` that matches the picture.

Comment: @JasperLyons that is one reason why posting the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is advised: so that people see *actual* code not *resembling* code.

Comment: This question although worded differently is very much similar to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807710/unexpected-output-when-printing-directly-to-text-video-memory . My answer covers this 64bit/32bit issue a the bottom (see the section `Likely Cause of Undefined Behavior`): http://stackoverflow.com/a/39878998/3857942

Comment: Since code posted has `0,1` reversed, perhaps true code has `'B', GREY_ON_BLACK` reversed also in `write_frame_buffer_cell('B', GREY_ON_BLACK, 0, 1);`.  It might be useful to read the offending data to know what values are there.

Comment: @weathervane Thanks, that's a great outline of how to ask a question. This is my first an though I took some steps to simplify the issue I didn't take all of those steps.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that question looks extremely similar. I've tried ensuring everything is outputing i386 (32bit) object files but have come across different problem (boot loop) which is likely a different issue.

Comment: @JasperLyons: 0xB8000 is always the start of the VGA console buffer, QEMU included. I read through the entire disassembly and don't see a problem with it. The suggestion that you're running 64-bit code while in 32-bit mode seems like your best bet; the encodings are *very* similar, and you would see things semi-randomly get incremented or decremented, and references to global variables would probably wind up accessing the wrong memory.

Comment: @icecreamsword If the VGA device detects a monochrome monitor it will boot in monochrome mode and a MDA compatible address of 0xB0000 will be used instead. This isn't something you'd normally have to worry about on modern PCs however.

Comment: Since you tagged this as x86-64. Was your intent to be in 64-bit longmode to begin with? If so the question is more involved since your `bootloader.asm` needs to be modified to enter longmode before transferring control to your kernel.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes I do mean triple fault! Thanks.

Comment: @icecreamsword I agree. After taking Michael Petch's suggestions I was able to get this working. I suspected that something was amiss when making the alterations but lacked the knowledge to track the issue down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your exact output if the code is modified to be:

```
unsigned int offset = frame_buffer_offset(0, 1);
write_memory(FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS, offset, 'A');
write_memory(FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS, offset + 1, GREY_ON_BLACK);

write_frame_buffer_cell('B', GREY_ON_BLACK, 1, 0);
```

The difference being in the last line `('B', GREY_ON_BLACK, 1, 0);`. Originally you had `('B', GREY_ON_BLACK, 0, 1);` . This is in line with what you described you were trying to do when you said:

> I've taken a screen shot of the output that I am getting. I expect 'A' to appear in the 0th column of the 1st row and for 'B' to appear on the 1st column of the 0th row.

I gather you may have posted the wrong code in this question. This is the output I get:

[image]

---

It seems you are new to OS development. Your bootloader code only places the CPU into 32-bit protected mode, but to run a 64-bit kernel you need to be in 64-bit longmode. If you are just getting started I'd suggest falling back to writing a 32-bit kernel for purposes of learning at this early stage. At the bottom I have a *64-bit long mode* section with a link to a longmode tutorial that could be used to modify your bootloader to run 64-bit code.

---

### Primary Issue Causing Unusual Behaviour

You are experiencing an issue primarily related to the fact that you are generating 64-bit code with *GCC* but you are running it in 32-bit protected mode according to your bootloader code. 64-bit code generation running in 32-bit protected mode may appear to execute, but it will do it incorrectly. In simple OSes where you are simply displaying to the video display you may often see unexpected output as a side effect. Your program could triple fault the machine, but you got unlucky that the side effect seemed to display something on the video display. You may have been under the false impression that things were working as they should when they really weren't.

This question is somewhat similar to another [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807710/unexpected-output-when-printing-directly-to-text-video-memory) question. After the original poster of that question made available a complete example it became clear that it was his issue. Part of my answer to him to resolve the issue was as follows:

> **Likely Cause of Undefined Behavior**
>
> After all the code and the make file were made available in *EDIT 2* it became clear that one significant problem was that most of the code was compiled and linked to 64-bit objects and executables. That code won't work in 32-bit protected mode.
>
> In the make file make these adjustments:
>
> - When compiling with *GCC* you need to add `-m32` option
> - When assembling with *GNU Assembler* (*as*) targeting 32-bit objects you need to use `--32`
> - When linking with *LD* you need to add the `-melf_i386` option
> - When assembling with *NASM* targeting 32-bit objects you need to change `-f elf64` to `-f elf32`

With that in mind you can alter your `Makefile` to generate 32-bit code. It could look like:

```
bootloader.bin: bootloader.asm
    nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin

bootkernel.o: bootkernel.asm
    nasm -f elf32 bootkernel.asm -o bootkernel.o

kernel.o: kernel.c
    gcc-6 -m32 -Wextra -Wall -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o

kernel.bin: bootkernel.o kernel.o linker.ld
    ld -melf_i386 -o kernel.bin -T linker.ld bootkernel.o kernel.o --oformat binary

os-image: bootloader.bin kernel.bin
    cat bootloader.bin kernel.bin > os-image

qemu: os-image
    qemu-system-x86_64 -d guest_errors -fda os-image -boot a
```

I gather when you started having issues with your code you ended up trying 0xb8002 as the address for your video memory. It should be 0xb8000. You'll need to modify:

```
#define FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS 0xb8002
```

To be:

```
#define FRAME_BUFFER_ADDRESS 0xb8000
```

Making all these changes should resolve your issues. This is what the output I got looked like after the changes mentioned above:

[image]

---

### Other observations

In `write_memory` you use:

```
unsigned char * memory = (unsigned char *) address;
```

Since you are using 0xb8000 that is memory mapped to the video display you should mark it as `volatile` since a compiler could optimize things away not knowing that there is a side effect to writing to that memory (namely displaying characters on a display). You might wish to use:

```
volatile unsigned char * memory = (unsigned char *) address;
```

---

In your `bootloader.asm` You really should explicitly set the A20 line on. You can find information about doing that in this [OSDev Wiki article](http://wiki.osdev.org/A20_Line). The status of the A20 line at the point a bootloader starts executing may vary between emulators. Failure to set it on could cause issues if you try to access memory areas on an odd numbered megabyte boundary (like 0x100000 to 0x1fffff, 0x300000 to 0x1fffff etc). Accesses to the odd numbered megabyte memory regions will actually read data from the even numbered memory region just below it. This is usually not behaviour you want.

---

### 64-bit long mode

If you want to run 64-bit code you will need to place the processor into 64-bit long mode. This is a bit more involved than entering 32-bit protected mode. Information on 64-bit longmode can be found in the [OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode). Once properly in 64-bit longmode you can use 64-bit instructions generated by *GCC*.

Comment: This is a great run own of the problem. Though in hindsight it seems perfectly sensible, it was not obvious to myself that 1. I was outputting 64bit code and 2. that 64bit code running in 32bit mode would appear to work. Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions! :)

Comment: @JasperLyons : Not a problem. When I saw your question and your `Makefile` I realized through experience (the other SO question) what the issue was. The way I found this issue originally (the other question) was to run the code through BOCHS with its internal debugger. As you step through the 64-bit instructions you'll realize that the instructions that were generated were not the same ones being being executed. That type of thing occurs in very few situations including generating code that is meant to be run in another mode. QEMU's debugger is very useful once in protected mode as well.

Comment: @JasperLyons : Were you originally trying to create a 64-bit kernel? The other option is spend the time modifying your bootloader to transition from 32-bit protected mode that you already have to 64-bit longmode. It is a bit involved since you have to enable paging which can be a bit difficult to understand if you are new to OS development and the X86's paging. If you did that then you could go back to creating 64-bit objects and 64-bit _C_ code.

Comment: I was indeed originally trying to create a 64-bit kernel but I discovered I was getting bogged down in the intricacies of boot loaders etc and not getting a lot of OS level stuff done. When I have a little more experience with the debugging tools and feel more confident in what I want to achieve with the OS I will return to moving into 64-bit longmode.

I am most certainly new to OS dev and X86 paging!

Comment: @JasperLyons If I get a chance on the weekend I'll expand the 64-bit longmode section in my answer that provides code to switch into 64-bit long mode.

Comment: that would be amazing. I've yet to come across a good walk through of the necessary steps and their justifications. I look forward to reading it :)