# execute a C++ procedure in an asm file using linker "ld"

Tags: c++, g++, x86-64, nasm, osdev

I have started with system programming, however I have reached a small impasse.
I do not know how to run a cpp procedure in an asm file using the NASM and g++ compilers.

This is my file kernel.asm :

```
[BITS 32]

EXTERN scrollup, print
global _start

_start :
    mov ax , msggdt
    push ax
    call print
    pop ax

    mov ax , msggdt32
    push ax
    call print
    pop ax

    mov ax , 3
    push ax
    call scrollup
    pop ax



end:
    jmp end

msggdt : db "Load gdt",13 , 10,0
msggdt32 : db "Load protected mode",13,10,0
```

and my cpp file contains the functions *print* and *scrollup*

My compilers are: NASM version 2.14 and gcc version 8.2.0 (Debian 8.2.0-21)

```
g++ -c screen.cpp
screen.cpp: In function ‘void _putcar_(uchar)’:
screen.cpp:63:59: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   video = (unsigned char*) (RAMSCREEN + 2 * kX + 160 * kY ) ;

nasm -f elf64 -o kernel.o kernel.asm
```

As you may notice, I have tried to call `ld` 4 times - not only to change the order of the objects, but also to change the output. However, there has been no effect.

```
ld --oformat binary -Ttext 1000 screen.o kernel.o  -o screen
ld: kernel.o: in function `_start':
kernel.asm:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `print'
ld: kernel.asm:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `print'
ld: kernel.asm:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `scrollup'


ld --oformat binary -Ttext 1000 screen.o kernel.o  -o kernel
ld: kernel.o: in function `_start':
kernel.asm:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `print'
ld: kernel.asm:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `print'
ld: kernel.asm:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `scrollup'

ld --oformat binary -Ttext 1000 kernel.o  screen.o -o kernel
ld: kernel.o: in function `_start':
kernel.asm:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `print'
ld: kernel.asm:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `print'
ld: kernel.asm:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `scrollup'

ld --oformat binary -Ttext 1000 kernel.o  screen.o -o screen
ld: kernel.o: in function `_start':
kernel.asm:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `print'
ld: kernel.asm:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `print'
ld: kernel.asm:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `scrollup'
```

Comment: In your C++ files the function calls that will be called from assembly need to be defined as `extern "C"` to drop the name mangling. Since you are building on Linux it implies you are likely generating ELF objects. Your C++ functions should not have a leading underscore on them (if you were on MacOS or native Windows that would be different).Since this isn't a [mcve] it is hard to tell what your C++ code looks like (I have to guess based on some of the errors)

Comment: Backing up Michael. You can use `readelf` to see the mangled name. Also be ware of the bitness of the whole thing: I see 16, 32 and 64-bit use/formats all together. Further, don't ignore warnings, especially when building an OS. Finally, it appears that you are using C++ but programming it like C, consider switching to the latter (it may be easier to deal with).

Comment: Margaret is correct.Given the comment about the GDT and the fact you are assembling with `-f elf64` itseems like you are tryignto create a 64-bit executable, you specify 32-bit assembly code generation with `bits 32` and yet your code seems to be for real mode.Unless you know waht you are doing, this is heading for a world of hurt since GCC's support for generating code that can rn in 16 bit mode is very lacking (it is a serious hack) even with the `-m16` GCC option.

Comment: I recommend using GRUB/Multiboot and don't create your own custom bootloader. Then you need to decide if you are writing a 64-bit OS or a 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

I could make the link. However, I used :

```
gcc -c screen.c
nasm -f elf64 -o kernel.o kernel.asm
```

So I had to have a c file instead of c ++ .. I do not understand why.
Could someone explain to me why it works?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments it is because C++ does [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++) on functions declarations.

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelPetch . It's true that my goal here is to compile my kernel code in protect mode with the gdt.
by the way, I compile my 32-bit format code, but for my c file, I do not know how to compile 32-bit formatting.
In addition, I expect that when I'm going to use ld, there will be an error like that it's incompatible with my i386 architecture: x86-64

In summary, hoping that this is the real problem:
how to compile my 32 bit c file to use my protect mode?
What are the parameters to use on ld to link my two resulting object files?

Comment: Your 16-bit bootloader would have to be built with `-f bin`, which I assume you are already doing. If you are building a 32-bit kernel, any `.asm` files related to your kernel that you assemble with NASM need to use `-felf32` (not `-f elf64`). You also need to compile all your _C_ files with option `-m32` (if you aren't using a cross compiler which it appears you aren't). If linking with _LD_ you would need to use `-melf_i386`

Comment: My last comment is also discussed in the section _Likely Cause of Undefined Behavior_ in one of my other [Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39878998/3857942)

Comment: @MichaelPetch By accepting to compile otherwise, and insofar as I want to create my own boot, I would like to know the reason for which, when I launch, it does not display any message declared in the kernel. Is this a bad configuration of the gdt?