# Unable to write to video memory from C code with variables

Tags: c, assembly, x86, osdev, vga

So I've been trying to write a basic kernel and I reached as far as writing to the screen.

I can do that very easily from **Assembly**, but not from **C**. Here is the code for writing to the screen from **Assembly**:

```
[bits 32]

VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x10

print_string_pm:
  pusha
  mov edx, VIDEO_MEMORY

print_string_pm_loop:
  mov al, [ebx]
  mov ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK

  cmp al, 0
  je print_string_pm_done

  mov [edx], ax

  add ebx, 1
  add edx, 2

  jmp print_string_pm_loop

print_string_pm_done:
  popa
  ret
```

And this works just fine, but then trying from the **C** code:

```
#define VIDEO_MEMORY 0xb8000
#define WHITE_ON_BLACK 0x0f

void main(void) {
    char* video_memory = (char*) VIDEO_MEMORY;

    *video_memory = 'H';
    *(video_memory + 2) = WHITE_ON_BLACK; 
    *(video_memory + 3) = 'e';
    *(video_memory + 5) = 'l';
    *(video_memory + 7) = 'l';
    *(video_memory + 9) = 'o';
    *(video_memory + 11) = ' ';
    *(video_memory + 13) = 'W';
    *(video_memory + 15) = 'o';
    *(video_memory + 17) = 'r';
    *(video_memory + 19) = 'l';
    *(video_memory + 21) = 'd';
}
```

This works but is not very efficient and then when i try declaring a string:

```
void main(void) {
    char* video_memory = (char*) VIDEO_MEMORY;
    char* str = "Hello World!";

    *video_memory = str[0];
    *(video_memory + 2) = WHITE_ON_BLACK;
    video_memory += 3;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        *(video_memory) = str[i];
        video_memory += 2;
    }
}
```

It just gives me weird things(like blank spaces or greek letters).
[image: qemu output]

My **Makefile**:

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard headers/*.h)

OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

all: build run

boot_sect.bin:bootloader/main.asm bootloader/gdt.asm bootloader/print_string_pm.asm bootloader/printf.asm bootloader/switch_to_pm.asm bootloader/readDisk.asm 
    nasm -i./bootloader/ -f bin bootloader/main.asm -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.bin **/*.o

clean_src: 
    rm -f src/*.o

run: image 
    qemu-system-x86_64 $< 

%.o: src/%.c ${HEADERS}
    gcc -I../headers/ -ffreestanding  -c $< -o build/$@

%.o: bootloader/%.asm
    nasm $<  -f elf64 -o build/$@

kernel.bin: ${OBJ} build/kernel_entry.o
    ld -o $@ -T link.ld $^ --oformat binary 

image: boot_sect.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > image

build: clean boot_sect.bin kernel.o kernel_entry.o kernel.bin image
```

Things I tried:

This creates an empty space for the letter **H** but the letter is not there and the space is **red**.

```c
typedef struct char_with_attribute {
    char ch, attribute;
} char_with_attribute;

char_with_attribute* convert_to_struct(char, char);

void main(void) {
    volatile char_with_attribute *video_memory = (void*)VIDEO_MEMORY;
    char* str = "Hello World!";

    *video_memory = *convert_to_struct('H', (char)0x0f);
}

char_with_attribute* convert_to_struct(char ch, char attr) {
    char_with_attribute* combination;

    combination->ch = ch;
    combination->attribute = attr;

    return combination;
}
```

Comment: Your assembly code seems to write the characters to even indices, and the attribute `WHITE_ON_BLACK` to every odd index. Your C code writes most of the characters to odd indices, and the attribute is only written to a single location at an even index.

Comment: You might want to have `volatile struct {char c, attrib;} *video_memory = (void*)VGA_BASE;` to help you sort out where you're putting things.

Comment: I don't know why but when I write from C to even indices it just doesn't work. Like nothing happens.

Comment: Perhaps the attribute bytes for those characters are black-on-black if you don't also write to the odd locations?  Anyway, your `convert_to_struct` function is broken because you're writing through an uninitialized pointer. (No memory protection in your OS I guess!) Look at compiler-generated asm if you want to find out what kind of nonsense happened, and in future **don't ignore compiler warnings!**  (Surprisingly, gcc only warns about using uninitialized with `-Wall`.)

Comment: You probably want to return a struct by value, or just use an anonymous struct object like `vidmem[1] = (struct foo){'H', 0xf};`.  Like https://godbolt.org/z/f9nb4v69E

Comment: Are you by chance generating 64-bit code and only put the processor in 32-bit mode? What you describe seems like it could be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807710/unexpected-output-when-printing-directly-to-text-video-memory

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're following [cfenollosa](https://github.com/cfenollosa)'s [os-tutorial](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial), or at least have stumbled upon a copy of its contents, as your assembly code snippet is from [chapter 08](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/blob/master/08-32bit-print/32bit-print.asm).

Simply, you write your character and attribute one byte after another, advancing your video memory offset each time. A crude example:

```
const char *s = "Hello world";
char *base = (void *) 0xb8000;

while (*s) {
    *base++ = *s++;
    *base++ = 0x0f;
}
```

[Chapter 15](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/15-video-ports) covers using the VGA I/O ports that deal with cursor position.

[Chapter 16](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/16-video-driver) introduces many higher level functions for writing to the screen in VGA text mode, many of which are specifically for dealing with the [80x25 boundaries](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/blob/master/16-video-driver/drivers/screen.c).

Comment: I have a feeling what is going on with the strange video output is that they have compiled/assembled the code as 64-bit and the processor is in 32-bit mode. Would explain the unusual output and may be a direct duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807710/unexpected-output-when-printing-directly-to-text-video-memory

Comment: That sounds familiar...I'm compiling it in 64-bit mode because it wouldn't let me with 32 bit mode...Here is my compile command `nasm $<  -f elf64 -o build/$@`. I also added the Makefile in the question.

Comment: @StanciuMihai In the answer to the other question I give examples on how to fix that. Build using NASM using `-felf32` . Compile with GCC using `-m32` and add the option `-melf_i386` to the linker options (LD). "  The answer I gave has a section "Likely Cause of Undefined Behavior" with those options mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39878998/3857942

Comment: Still doesn't work after adding all these options. Here is the output from running `make`. ```ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `src/kernel.o' is incompatible with i386 output
ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `src/mem.o' is incompatible with i386 output
ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `src/screen.o' is incompatible with i386 output```

Comment: Here is the repo on github in case you need it https://github.com/mstanciu552/basic_os

Comment: @StanciuMihai Did you clean all the files so all of them are rebuilt with the new options? Sounds like the object files weren't rebuilt and the old 64-bit ones were still present. Do a `make clean` first and then rebuild

Comment: I have tried both `make clean` and cleaning the output by hand...Nothing works

Comment: Also there is something strange that may be related... after everything is compiled and I compile the **assembly file that calls the C code** some command with **cc** is called automatically ```gcc -m32 -I../headers/ -ffreestanding  -c src/kernel.c -o build/kernel.o
nasm bootloader/kernel_entry.asm  -felf32 -o build/kernel_entry.o
cc    -c -o src/kernel.o src/kernel.c
cc    -c -o src/mem.o src/mem.c
cc    -c -o src/screen.o src/screen.c``` I've been trying to get rid of it but I can't seem to

Comment: @StanciuMihai : you may be better off asking that as a new question.