# Unable to print anything to display

Tags: c, x86, osdev

I'm having trouble printing anything to the display in my OS I'm working on. I tried to follow the OSdev Meaty Skeleton tutorial, but I'm still stuck. It does not print anything and doesn't even move the cursor.

I did manage to (somewhat) get characters out by using `volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8000`, and then manually do `video[0] = 'X'`, but my actual terminal code still won't work and it doesn't even print multiple characters (I took into account how `video[1]` needs to be a color but it still was just garbled when I tried to do it.

Any and all help is appreciated, I can add more code if required. Thank you so much!
P.S. This is protected mode if it helps

The kernel.c code:

```
#include "include/libc/stdbool.h" // Booleans
#include "include/libc/stdint.h" // Integer declarations
#include "include/graphics.h" // Graphics handling
#include "include/terminal.h" // Terminal handling





void kmain() {
    initTerminal(); // Initialize terminal.
    printf("Test string.\n");
    
}
```

The graphics.h code (contains the declarations for video mem and other stuff):

```
// graphics.h - Header file for graphics.c
// Note that graphics.c and terminal.c are different. One houses the main code for anything graphics related(drawing, colors, etc) and the other handles console output and misc. other functions.
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

#include "include/libc/stdint.h" // Integer declarations
#include "include/libc/stdbool.h" // Boolean declarations
#include "include/libc/stddef.h" // size_t declaration
#include "include/libc/string.h" // String functions


// Basic graphics definitions, like the video memory address
static const uint16_t* VIDEO_MEM = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
static const size_t SCREEN_WIDTH = 80;
static const size_t SCREEN_HEIGHT = 25; 

// Color enumerator.
enum gfxColor {
    COLOR_BLACK = 0,
    COLOR_BLUE = 1,
    COLOR_GREEN = 2,
    COLOR_CYAN = 3,
    COLOR_RED = 4,
    COLOR_MAGENTA = 5,
    COLOR_BROWN = 6,
    COLOR_LIGHT_GRAY = 7,
    COLOR_DARK_GRAY = 8,
    COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE = 9,
    COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN = 10,
    COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN = 11,
    COLOR_LIGHT_RED = 12,
    COLOR_LIGHT_MAGENTA = 13,
    COLOR_LIGHT_BROWN = 14,
    COLOR_WHITE = 15
};

// vgaEntry() - Functions returns a valid VGA character entry.
// Parameters: unsigned char uc and uint8_t color
static inline uint16_t vgaEntry(unsigned char uc, uint8_t color) { return (uint16_t) uc | (uint16_t) color << 8; }

// vgaColorEntry() - Function returns a valid VGA color entry.
// Parameters: Two gfxColor enums, foreground color and background color
static inline uint8_t vgaColorEntry(enum gfxColor foreground, enum gfxColor background) { return foreground | background << 4; }
#endif
```

My terminal code:

```
// ===================================================================
// terminal.c - Handles all terminal functions for graphics
// ===================================================================
// This file is a part of the reduceOS C kernel. Please credit me if you use this code.

#include "include/terminal.h" // This header file contains variable declarations as not to clutter up the actual C code.



// initTerminal() - Load the terminal, setup the buffers, reset the values, etc.
void initTerminal(void) {
    terminalX = 0, terminalY = 0; // Reset terminal X and Y
    terminalColor = vgaColorEntry(COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_CYAN); // The terminal color will be white for the text and cyan for the BG on start.
    terminalBuffer = VIDEO_MEM; // Initialize the terminal buffer as VIDEO_MEM (0xB8000)

    // Now we need to setup the screen by clearing it with ' '.

    for (size_t y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH; x++) {
            const size_t index = y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x;
            terminalBuffer[index] = vgaEntry(' ', terminalColor);
        }
    }
}


// updateTerminalColor(uint8_t color) - Update the terminal color. Simple function.
// Why not use gfxColors as the params? Other functions in terminal.c call this, and it's faster to use terminalColor. May change later though.
void updateTerminalColor(uint8_t color) { terminalColor = color; }


// terminalPutcharXY(unsigned char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y) - Specific function to place a vgaEntry() at a specific point on the screen.
void terminalPutcharXY(unsigned char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y) {
    const size_t index = y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x; // Same code as in initTerminal(). Calculate index to place char at and copy it.
    terminalBuffer[index] = vgaEntry(c, color);
}

// Unlike the alpha, this one has terminal scrolling (wiki.osdev.org)!
// scrollTerminal(int line) - Scrolls a line downwards.
void scrollTerminal(int line) {
    int *loop;
    char c;

    for (loop = line * (SCREEN_WIDTH * 2) + VIDEO_MEM; loop < SCREEN_WIDTH * 2; loop++) {
        c = *loop;
        *(loop - (SCREEN_WIDTH * 2)) = c;
    }
}


// terminalDeleteLastLine() - delete the last line of the terminal. Useful for scrolling.
void terminalDeleteLastLine() {
    int x, *ptr;

    for (x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH * 2; x++) {
        ptr = VIDEO_MEM + (SCREEN_WIDTH * 2) * (SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1) + x;
        *ptr = 0;
    }
}


// terminalPutchar(char c) - This is the recommended function to use (besides printf, that'll be later) as it incorporates scrollTerminal and terminalDeleteLastLine.
void terminalPutchar(char c) {
    int line;
    unsigned char uc = c; // terminalPutcharXY() requires an unsigned char.

    terminalPutcharXY(uc, terminalColor, terminalX, terminalY); // Place an entry at terminal X and Y.

    // Perform the scrolling stuff
    if (++terminalX == SCREEN_WIDTH) {
        terminalX = 0;
        if (++terminalY == SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
            for (line = 1; line <= SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1; line++) { scrollTerminal(line); }
            terminalDeleteLastLine();
            terminalY = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1;
        }
    }
}

// terminalWrite(const char *data, size_t size) - Writes a certain amount of data to the terminal.
void terminalWrite(const char *data, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) terminalPutchar(data[i]);
}


// terminalWriteString() - The exact same as terminal write, but shorter with no len option (we use strlen). Not recommended for use, use printf (further down in the file)!
void terminalWriteString(const char *data) { terminalWrite(data, strlen(data)); }


// *************************************************************************************************
// Some of the following functions are helper functions to printf, as they need to return a value. 
// It is not recommended to use them and they are not included in the header.
// They may be removed and existing functions will be updated to return include values.
// *************************************************************************************************


// putc(int ic) - terminalPutchar with return values.
int putc(int ic) {
    char c = (char) ic;
    terminalWrite(&c, sizeof(c));
    return ic;
}


// print(const char* data, size_t length) - terminalWrite with return values.
static bool print(const char *data, size_t length) {
    const unsigned char* bytes = (const unsigned char*) data;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (putc(bytes[i]) == -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// Now we move to the actual main function, printf.

// printf(const char* format, ...) - The most recommended function to use. Don't know why I didn't opt for a libc file but whatever. This prints something but has formatting options and multiple arguments.
int printf(const char* restrict format, ...) {
    int charsWritten = 0;
    char **arg = (char **)&format; // This references the arguments in printf. It will increment to go to the next argument (as we don't have a name for it)

    while (*format != '\0') { // Continue the while loop until c = \0, signaling the end of the string.
        size_t maxrem = INT_MAX - charsWritten; // maxrem helps prevent overflow errors (for security and for bugs)

        // Handling percents in the string. Following if statements are about %s, %c, etc.
        if (format[0] != '%' || format[1] == '%') {
            if (format[0] == '%') format++;
            size_t amnt = 1;
            while (format[amnt] && format[amnt] != '%') amnt++;

            if (maxrem < amnt) return -1; // Overflow
            if (!print(format, amnt)) return -1; // Print error.

            format += amnt;
            charsWritten += amnt;
            continue;
        }
        
        const char* formatStartsAt = format++;

        
        if (*format == 'c') { // Taking care of %c
            format++;
            char c = (char) arg++;
            if (!maxrem) return -1; // Overflow
            if (!print(&c, sizeof(c))) return -1; // Print error.

        } else if (*format == 's') { // Taking care of %s
            format++;
            const char* str = *arg++;
            size_t len = strlen(str);

            if (maxrem < len) return -1; // Overflow
            if (!print(str, len)) return -1; // Print error.

        } else { // If there are no modifiers at all.
            format = formatStartsAt;
            size_t len = strlen(format);
            
            if (maxrem < len) return -1; // Overflow
            if (!print(format, len)) return -1; // Print error.

            charsWritten += len;
            format += len;
        }
        
    }

    return charsWritten;
}
```

Thank you again!

**UPDATE #1: I tried calling `terminalPutchar` and `terminalPutcharXY` directly but it still didn't work. I also noticed I forgot to show the type of terminal.h! It's a `uint16_t *`. I did notice something odd: I noticed others were using `unsigned char*` as a declaration for `VIDEO_MEM` and `terminalBuffer`, but that completely crashed QEMU.**

**Also, I updated the code to include a new change of `VIDEO_MEM`, from `uint16_t` to `uint16_t *`.

Comment: Bisect your problem. Find out if the problem is with parsing the format string, or writing to screen. Have you tried to call `terminalPutchar` or `terminalPutcharXY` directly? Did you get the expected result?

Comment: @HAL9000 Apologies for the late response! I tried calling both methods to no avail. It doesn't register they've even been called, as the cursor doesn't move at all (the ASM code prints something out so it's not in the place it is on start)

Comment: I hope you aren't compiling this as 64-bit code and only put the processor into 32-bit protected mode? Whatever your problem is, it probably has to do with your bootloader; the way things are set up; or how you build things. Without seeing a complete projetc this may be near impossible to troubleshoot. You might want to put your code on Github and ask over on https://forum.osdev.org/

Comment: @MichaelPetch That's it, for sure. I just realized I am compiling the kernel's loader with `-f elf64` instead of `-f elf32`. I'll fix it and come back here. One question: What argument should I put for CC?

Comment: @MichaelPetch That did it! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Rather than answer this question I'm going to close it as a duplicate of another answer I made. I should point out that the clue for the possibility about it being 64-bit code in 32-bit protected mode is that one of the first side effect that many people see is strange unexpected output when writing to the video display. See this question and my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807710/unexpected-output-when-printing-directly-to-text-video-memory

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, my apologies.